# Google spreadsheets - find value it two-dimensional table by two parameters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two-dimensional matrix (or let's say table) with values for each combination of parameters.

Also there is the second table that have two parameters. How can I get value from the first table for specific combination of parameters?

[image]

Here's example - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157uQZFG2FzMvgCezH8PsAfmdOtjbPMVtTUUU6-K-C6c/edit?usp=sharing

Cell D8 should be 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=filter(filter(B2:D4,B1:D1=C8),A2:A4=B8)
```

OR

```
=index(B2:D4,xmatch(B8,A2:A4),xmatch(C8,B1:D1))
```